how could I let cmake support cuda __half types?
I am trying to write a lib based on CUDA, and I need to use FP16 (the __half type) ops. A basic code is like this:
// main.cu
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_fp16.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>



__device__ __forceinline__
bool operator<(const __half a, const __half b) {
    return __hlt(a, b);
}

__device__ __forceinline__
bool operator<=(const __half a, const __half b) {
    return __hle(a, b);
}

__device__ __forceinline__
bool operator>(const __half a, const __half b) {
    return __hgt(a, b);
}

__device__ __forceinline__
bool operator>=(const __half a, const __half b) {
    return __hge(a, b);
}

And my CMakeLists.txt is like this:
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 3.22)

PROJECT(fp16 LANGUAGES CUDA CXX)

#  command:
# cmake ..


link_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/build)

add_definitions (CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release)
add_definitions (CMAKE_CUDA_FLAGS_RELEASE="-O2 -DNDEBUG")
add_definitions (CMAKE_CUDA_ARCHITECTURES=90)


enable_language (CUDA)
find_package (CUDAToolkit)
include (CheckLanguage)
check_language (CUDA)
add_library(main SHARED main.cu)
target_compile_features(main PUBLIC cuda_std_17)

## deprecated
# set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++17 -O2")
# set(CMAKE_NVCC_FLAGS "-std=c++20 -O2")
# find_package(CUDA REQUIRED)
# link_directories(/usr/local/cuda/lib64)
# cuda_add_library(main SHARED main.cu)
# target_link_libraries(
#     main
#     ${CUDA_LIBRARIES}
# )
# target_include_directories(
#     main PUBLIC ${CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${CUDNN_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
# add_executable (main main.cu)

But I got the error message like this:
/tmp/main.cu(10): error: identifier "__hlt" is undefined
      return __hlt(a, b);
             ^

/tmp/main.cu(15): error: identifier "__hle" is undefined
      return __hle(a, b);
             ^

/tmp/main.cu(20): error: identifier "__hgt" is undefined
      return __hgt(a, b);
             ^

/tmp/main.cu(25): error: identifier "__hge" is undefined
      return __hge(a, b);
             ^

4 errors detected in the compilation of "/tmp/main.cu".

The code and build/ dir and its contens can be downloaded here .
What did I miss, and how could I make it work?

Since CUDA has language support in CMake find_package(CUDA) and cuda_add_library are deprecated. Don't use them. Just do enable_language(CUDA). CMake should b able to find the CUDA Toolkit in its default location(s) automatically, so no need for link_directories(/usr/local/cuda/lib64) either. If one wants to use specific CUDA libraries from C++ code, one now uses find_package(CUDAToolkit) which provides lots of targets to link against.

You should also use #include <...> to avoid that the preprocessor first searches these external headers in the project directory.

@paleonix I still have same problem after following your instructions, I modified my code in the question accordingly, would you tell me how to make this work？

The current code works for me. Have you purged your build directory?

Note that find_package(CUDAToolkit), target_link_libraries(main ${CUDA_LIBRARIES}) and target_include_directories(main PUBLIC ${CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${CUDNN_INCLUDE_DIRS}) are not needed/don't do anything in this context.

For specifying the needed C++ standard for CUDA targets, CMake has target_compile_features(main PUBLIC cuda_std_20) (might be PRIVATE). Please generally avoid specifying the optimization level (-O2) in the CMake file. It should be specified at configuration time (i.e. when you call cmake the first time) like the CUDA architecture(s). I.e. cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_CUDA_FLAGS_RELEASE="-O2 -DNDEBUG" -DCMAKE_CUDA_ARCHITECTURES=90.

If it still does not work after purging your build directory, please include the configuration/generation output from your first CMake call in the empty build directory in you question.

@paleonix Hi, I still cannot make it work, even if I clean up whole build and recreate it. I added a link to my code in the updated question, would you please have a review on it?

@paleonix It seems that cuda works well if I do not use fp16 operations. The problem seems to be associated with the options of __hlt and so on.

add_definitions is for compile switches such as -DNDEBUG. I don't think that works with (CMAKE_CUDA_ARCHITECTURES) Try set_property(TARGET main PROPERTY CUDA_ARCHITECTURES 90) for this specifically. Otherwise us the general set as in set(CMAKE_CUDA_ARCHITECTURES 90)

I guess the fact that I recommended cmake -D... for configuration caused confusion. -D on the CMake command is for setting CMake variables. It is not yhe same as e.g. gcc -D.... Also my point was not to hardcode these things such that one has the flexibility to change them when needed without editing the CMakeLists.txt. And for completeness:  I expected the CUDA architecturd number to be replaced with the one fitting for OP.

And I testet used the source code from the question so the problem does not seem to be (easily) reproducible. Again: Please include the configuration output from CMake which should tell us about compiler versions. And the CMake version might also be important.

Did you identify the issue?

@paleonix Yes, I change add_difinitions into set and the problem is solved now. And I tried to use cmake .. -DXXX, it also works. Would you please add an answer so that I can accept it ?

It might be a good idea to include the if(NOT DEFINED CMAKE_CUDA_ARCHITECTURES) set(CMAKE_CUDA_ARCHITECTURES …) stuff from this page to provide a meaningful default but also allow overriding it from the commandline. Instead of hardcoding 90 you can set it to native starting in cmake 3.24, see here

Are you sure you want an answer written for your question in its current state? Because right now the problem with your code is just your misunderstanding of my previous comment. You or I could rollback the edits since my initial formatting edit which would allow me to create a more useful answer I think.
